# Maximising a finite sum of cosines, of different but known amplitude, frequency and phase?

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis

Is there an analytical approach to maximising a finite sum of cosines, of different but known amplitude, frequency and phase?

$A=\Sigma_i^N A_i \cos \left(\phi_i t - g_i\right)$

I wish to find $A_{\max}$ (or $t_{\max}$, the time when the maximum occurs). 
I know that $t_{\max}$ is not necessarily unique. The case when $g_i=0$ is trivial, in that case $A_{\max}=\Sigma_i^N A_i$ . For $\phi_i$ all the same, we have [phasor addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor#Addition). But I can't figure out how to approach the general case.

The context is tidal prediction - the tidal constituents have known frequencies (they arise from astronomical events) $\phi_i$, and each has an amplitude $A_i$ and phase $g_i$ that has been derived by fitting to a few months' data. N is typically 26 - 100 or so.  But then we wish to predict the maximum tidal range, and although I can manually produce the series $A=\Sigma_i^N A_i \cos (\phi_i t - g_i)$ for some large range of $t$ and find the maximums, that's too slow for my purposes.

Any suggestions?